# How to disable intellisense of a specific source in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to stop Intellisense from any specific source like Font Awesome or bootstrap, because they show some unnecessary suggestions.
"editor.quickSuggestions":false. is not a solution, as it disables suggestions of all the sources. 
Thank You so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "intellisense from"? Can you be more specific and give an example of what you mean?